# Defining contrast between different levels of treatments in emmeans

Tags: r, contrast, emmeans

I'm analyzing a fertilization experiment with 5 treatments, namely:

1_Control,
2_Fertilizer_A,
3_Fertilizer_B,
4_Fertilizer_C, and
5_Fertilizer_D

Also, Fertilizer A to D were evaluated under different doses (40, 80, 120 and 160 Kg hectare-1).

My goal is to evaluate if there is any combination of "fertilizer x dose" that is effective in overcoming the "Control" (Control does not include fertilizer).

I've fitted the following model to get the quadratic response curve and find the optimum rate:

```
ModelFert <- lmer (yield ~ treatment + dose + dose2 + 
              (1 | environment/block/cultivar) + 
              (0 + dose + dose2 || treatment:environment),
              data = fert)
```

The model worked perfectly with significant results for treatments. Output graph:

[image]

To address my goal, I need to perform contrasts . Briefly, "Control" vs. "fertilizers x different doses". To do so, I'm running the following code:

```
marginal = emmeans(ModelFert, ~ treatment, at = list(rate_mgha = 100)) #opt. dose= 100 kg ha-1 
CLD = cld(marginal, alpha=0.05,reversed=TRUE, Letters=LETTERS)
CLD
```

The problem here is that, the comparison is made with the "Control" treatment under a fertilizer dose of 100 kg hectare-1, which is in fact, impossible (control does not include fertilizer).

Could anyone provide me with some clues in how to fit a contrast among treatments at different fertilizer levels keeping the control at zero rate? (That is: Control at zero rate vs. any fertilizer at 100 kg fertilazer/ha)

I reviewed the topic online and no clear clues founded!

Thank you so much in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not know how to achieve this with `emmeans`, but it is easy to do [using the `marginaleffects` package.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/) (Disclaimer: I am the author.)

First, we load the package and fit a model. Since you did not provide data, I am using the `mtcars` dataset, where `gear` is your treatment and `hp` is your fertilizer:

```r
library(marginaleffects)

mod <- lm(mpg ~ factor(gear) + hp, mtcars)
```

Then, we create a prediction grid, with one row per treatment arm (`gear`), and different baseline values of fertilizer (`hp`) for each treatment:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
    gear = c(3, 4, 5),
    hp = c(100, 110, 110))

dat
#>   gear  hp
#> 1    3 100
#> 2    4 110
#> 3    5 110
```

Now, we use the `predictions()` function to compute [adjusted predictions](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/predictions.html) for each of the groups:

```r
predictions(mod, newdata = dat)
#>   rowid     type predicted std.error statistic       p.value
#> 1     1 response  21.19650 1.1705800  18.10769  2.771147e-73
#> 2     2 response  23.16282 0.9381255  24.69054 1.351597e-134
#> 3     3 response  27.10272 1.6979850  15.96170  2.362147e-57
#>   conf.low conf.high gear  hp
#> 1 18.79868  23.59433    3 100
#> 2 21.24116  25.08448    4 110
#> 3 23.62456  30.58089    5 110
```

Finally, we use the `hypothesis` argument to specify a custom contrast. This will use the delta method to compare the predictions in the first treatment level to the average of predictions in the other two treatment arms:

```r
predictions(mod, newdata = dat,
    hypothesis = c(-1, .5, .5))
#>       type   term predicted std.error statistic     p.value conf.low
#> 1 response custom  3.936269   1.26463  3.112586 0.001854562  1.45764
#>   conf.high
#> 1  6.414898
```

The `hypothesis` argument is quite powerful. You can read more about it here: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/hypothesis.html

Comment: It appears that the hypothesis shown here compares one group with the average of all the others. What the OP wants, I think is comparisons of one group with *each* of the others, separately. My answer shows how to do that in **emmeans**; it appears there is substantial overlap in our packages' capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I misunderstood the question. Yes, there is substantial overlap, but `emmeans` remains considerably more powerful. Your work is amazing and an inspiration!

Comment: Hi Russ and Vincent, many thanks for the replies. I really appreciate them! Below Russ reply I'm outlining some comments! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As I read it, the stated objectives are to obtain predictions (not marginal means) for each *combination* of treatment and dose, and to compare each of those with the prediction for the control condition. If that is so, then two things stand out in the procedure displayed that are contrary to those goals:

1. Obtaining `marginal`. This averages over the doses (as is implied BTW by the term "marginal"), thus not providing estimates for the combinations of the two factors.
2. Using `cld()`. This is a way of doing all pairwise comparisons, as opposed to doing selected ones, i.e. each with control. (In addition, CLDs are at best a poor way of showing pairwise comparisons.)
3. I know I said two things, but I also question the model you fitted; and the meaning of `dose2` is not explained in the OP. I suspect it creates a nesting structure that accounts for the fact that the control group can have no `dose` effect.

Here is something that might work. First, obtain the means for each condition:

```
M <- emmeans(ModelFert, ~ treatment * dose * dose2)
M   # displays the estimates
```

One of the estimates shown (I hope) is that of the control group that we want to contrast everything with. Suppose it is the 7th one. Then obtain the contrasts accordingly, changing `7` with the appropriate index:

```
contrast(M, "trt.vs.ctrl", ref = 7)
```

All this said, since you are interested in *combinations* of the factors, I think it is probably a mistake to have a model with only additive effects of `treatment` and `dose`. So I strongly recommend using the model with interaction:

```
ModelFert2 <- lmer (yield ~ treatment * dose + dose2 + 
          (1 | environment/block/cultivar) + 
          (0 + rate_mgha + rate2_mgha || treatment:environment),
          data = fert)
```

Then use analogous code `M2 <- emmeans(ModelFert2, ...)` and `contrast(M2, ...)`.

#### Addendum

Now that I understand that `dose` is a quantitative predictor, and that `dose2` equals `dose^2`, the plot thickens somewhat.

The second matter first: `emmeans` assumes that *each predictor can be varied independently of the others*. That is not the case here because you cannot have `dose2` at any value other than `dose^2`. There are various remedies, but the easiest and most reliable one is to re-fit the model:

```
ModelFert3 <- lmer (yield ~ treatment * (dose + I(dose^2)) + 
              (1 | environment/block/cultivar),
              data = fert)
```

Yes, I put the interaction in the fixed-effects part of the model, where it belongs. I would never fit the model shown in the OP; I should have examined it more closely.

That done, the main issue is specifying the different dose levels and then getting the contrasts. Here, I suggest

```
EMM <- emmeans(ModelFert3, ~ treatment * dose,
               at = list(dose = c(0, 40, 80, 120, 160))
EMM <- EMM[-c(2:5, 6, 11, 16, 21)]
EMM    # List the means to make sure you have it right
contrast(EMM, "trt.vs.ctrl1")
```

The first statement creates a grid of 25 means for the combinations of 5 treatments and 5 doses. However, you don't want some of them because the first treatment occurs only with `dose = 0`, and `dose = 0` occurs only with the first treatment. This leaves us with the 17 combinations we are actually interested in. Then the `contrast` call compares the first one with each of the others.

Comment: Hi Russ, some comments: i)_ "dose2" is the quadratic term of the model (I edited the original post) and ii)_Interaction between treatment and dose is denoted in the random term of the model `(0 + dose + dose2 || treatment:environment)`. I was wondering how to do the contrast between "Control at dose= zero" and "any Fertilizer at dose = 100 kg ha-1".  The contrast you provide works perfectly but the comparison is made under the averaged dose. Thank you so much again!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I think we got it. The code that work is:

```
emm1 = emmeans(ModelFert,~treatment*dose, at=list (dose= 100))
emm2 = emmeans(ModelFert,~treatment*dose, at=list (dose= 0))
emm3 = emm2[1] + emm1      # or rbind(emm2[1], emm1)
     
confint(emm3, adjutst= "none")

contrast(emm3, "trt.vs.ctrl")
```

The important thing in these cases is to create two sets of emmeans, and then merge them to finally do the contrast between treatments at different levels. I found the clue in a post made from Russ Lenth!

Comment: This will be incorrect. See the addendum to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @RussLenth!! The code you suggested in the addendum section worked perfectly!! Also, I appreciate your comments and explanations on the topic!